# How to choose $n$ balls from the bags?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Given $4$ bags A, B, C and D.

Bag **A** contains **'a'** number of balls.

Bag **B** contains **'b'** number of balls.

Bag **C** contains **'c'** number of balls.

Bag **D** contains **'d'** number of balls.

I have another bag **E** that contains infinite number of balls.

Now, I have another bag **F** and I need to fill in **n** balls in it such that **atmost $1$** ball can be chosen from bags A,B,C and D and there is no restriction on the number of balls to be chosen from bag E.

So,I need to find the number of ways to choose **n** balls and fill bag **F** with it.

**My Approach:** Build Cases based on the balls chosen from bag 'F'.

But the problem arises when I have to choose balls from bags A,B,C and D.

Comment: Does $a$ > $n$?

Comment: @openspace Doesn't matter as either i can pick 1 ball out of total **a** balls or none at all from Bag A.

Comment: Hint:  if $n≥4$ then you can pick from any subset of $\{A,B,C,D\}$ so the answer, in this case, would just be the number of subsets.

Comment: @vidhan why? If $a$ > $n-4$ I could pick all *needed* balls from A. But if there is no such amount of balls then I couldn't do it

Comment: @openspace I believe the OP is saying that we can choose either $0$ or $1$ ball from $A$.  The $a$ is a red herring (unless $a=0$, I suppose.  I was ignoring that case).

Comment: @lulu there is also a bag E with infinite number of balls.

Comment: @lulu ok, I understand it

Comment: @lulu Yes we can choose either 0 or 1 ball from A.Similar is the case for B,C,D except E.

Comment: @vidhan  Of course.  $E$ takes up the slack.  So, say $n=63$ and your subset was $\{C,D\}$.  then you take $1$ from $C$, $1$ from $D$ and $61$ from $E$.

Comment: @lulu or i can take all from E.

Comment: @vidhan  Absolutely.  That corresponds to choosing $\emptyset$ as your subset.

Comment: @almagest there would also be a case when I draw $n - 3$ balls from E and have to chose other $3$ balls from either A,B,C or A,B,D or B,C,D or A,C,D.

Comment: @vidhan Yes, those are part of the 16 possibilities. If you like you can say you have 1 possibility where you draw $n$ from $E$, 4 where you draw $n-1$ from $E$, 6 where you draw $n-2$ from $E$, 4 where you draw $n-3$ from $E$ and 1 where you draw $n-4$ from $E$. I should have said the "remaining" rather than the "remaining $n-4$". But it is quicker to say you have 2 choices for $A$, 2 for $B$, 2 for $C$, 2 for $D$ and only one for $E$ (provided $n\ge4).

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ you have 5 choices: you can take the ball from any of $A,B,C,D,E$.

For $n=2$ you have 11 choices: you can take both balls from $E$, or one from $E$ and the other from any of $A,B,C,D$ (4 choices), or you can take one from each of two of $A,B,C,D$ (6 choices).

For $n=3$ you have 15 choices: you can take all three from $E$ (1 choice), or two from $E$ and one from one of $A,B,C,D$ (4 choices) or one from $E$ and one from each of two of $A,B,C,D$ (6 choices), or none from $E$ and one from each of three of $A,B,C,D$ (4 choices).

For $n=4$ you have 16 choices: for each of $A,B,C,D$ you can choose to take 0 or 1, so that is a total of $2^4=16$ choices. You then must take the remainder from $E$.

A shorthand for this is that: for $n=1$ you have ${4\choose0}+{4\choose1}=5$ choices; for $n=2$ you have ${4\choose0}+{4\choose1}+{4\choose2}=11$ choices; for $n=3$ you have ${4\choose0}+{4\choose1}+{4\choose2}+{4\choose3}=15$ choices; and for $n\ge4$ you have ${4\choose0}+{4\choose1}+{4\choose2}+{4\choose3}+{4\choose4}=2^4=16$ choices. The binomial ${4\choose r}$ corresponds to taking a total of $r$ from $A,B,C,D$ and the rest from $E$.